# concatenate array of images together in one sourcefile

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to concatenate array of images in foreach loop. Each value I wanna insert `|` in between the values. The files are in the folder storage/uploads/stl What I expect is something like this:

This is what I have tried so far. I tried in Raw PHP

```
$lstfile = $project->labstlfiles;
 $explodeItems = json_decode($lstfile);
 print_r($explodeItems);

Output array :
stdClass Object ( [labstlfiles] => Array ( [0] => scans.stl_1570736143.stl [1] => lower.stl_1570736143.stl [2] => stl.stl_1570736143.stl ) )
```

Then am looping in a conditional statement like this:

```
    <?php   if (is_object($explodeItems)){ ?>
     <?php foreach ($explodeItems->labstlfiles as $items) { ?>
     <div class="view" style="background-color: yellow">
     <canvas id="fullscreen" class="3dviewer" sourcefiles="{{asset("storage/uploads/stl/". $items . "|") }}" width="960px" height="600px"></canvas>
     </div>
     <?php }
      }else{                        
      echo '<h2> It is not array </h2>
       }
       ?>
```

What I get is 3 instances of the array with each file working in a div. I want one source file with all three files combining to give me 3d object. Thanks

Comment: [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<canvas id="fullscreen" class="3dviewer" sourcefiles='@foreach($explodeItems->labstlfiles as $item){{asset("storage/uploads/stl/$item")}}|@endforeach ' width="960px" height="600px"></canvas>`